# p/invoke method returns empty struct

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have C++ code that contains a struct and I need to pass it to C#:

wrapper.h

```
#pragma once
typedef struct
{
    int     int1;
    int     int2;
} MY_STRUCT;

MY_STRUCT mystruct;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall GetTestStruct(MY_STRUCT* cs_struct);
```

wrapper.cpp:

```
int __stdcall GetTestStruct(MY_STRUCT* cs_struct)
{
    mystruct.int1 = 23;
    mystruct.int2 = 45;
    cs_struct = &mystruct;
    return 0;
}
```

wrapper.cs:

```
class Program
{
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct MY_STRUCT
  {
    public int int1;
    public int int2;
  }

  [DllImport(VpxMctlPath)]
  public static extern int GetTestStruct(ref MY_STRUCT mystruct);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var s = new MY_STRUCT();
    GetTestStruct(ref s);
  }
}
```

After I run this code, s still has zeros for int1 and int2. I've tried to make the C# struct fields private and public, but no difference. I looked at C++/CLI, but that seems overkill for this small task. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Code is as simple as it can be.   You code isn't working because you need to allocate the structure in c# in unmanaged memory space using : IntPtr s = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(myStruct));  Then in c++ code you have to write data to cs_struct=>int1 = 23; and cs_struct=>int2 = 45;

Comment: @RyanWilson, It works. Submits as an answer.

Comment: @KevinS.Miller Submitted. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your C++ function to set the integer values directly on the referenced struct:

```
int __stdcall GetTestStruct(MY_STRUCT* cs_struct)
{
    cs_struct->int1 = 23;
    cs_struct->int2 = 45;
    //cs_struct = *mystruct; //This line may not be necessary
    return 0;
}
```